# Generate end points from a layer that contains multiple lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2

I generate a layer file that has multiple parallel lines, that I want is to sequentially (from OBJECTID(1) to OBJECTID(Max)) create a point at each end point of the line segments and number these points. The other problem is alternating which side it starts creating a point from...

Say I have 2 lines parallel to each other going left to right and one is above the other. The first line would have a point at the left-end point labeled 1, the right-end point labeled 2. The next line would have the right end-point labeled 3, and the left end-point labeled 4 and so on.

Comment: Look at feature vertices to points (Advanced license only) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000 and use either "START" or "BOTH_ENDS" depending on your requirements. If you don't have advanced or that solution isn't suitable please draw a picture with the lines and points and I'll help you through the arcpy.

Comment: My organization won't be upgrading from 10.0 to 10.2 for another year (which means our advanced licenses won't migrate until then) but I did convince them to let me upgrade one of the 10.0 licenses to a 10.2 basic for testing. 

http://i.imgur.com/RA3g4Ay.png - I already have made a couple python scripts that will generate those lines automatically but making end-points and alternating them is becoming a difficult task. I just labeled the first 6 points (3 lines)... They may not always be horizontal tho.

http://pastebin.com/8WuZ7MJX - I already made a script that will alternate a field

Comment: Feature vertices to points has been almost the same since 8.3 (not a misprint, version **8.3** was when I went from ArcINFO to ArcMap) the only part that's changed is "DANGLE" which appears to be new but I'm not sure when that became an option. With the points you can perform *Near* http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000 or perform a spatail join to add fields to join to the contributing lines if not already present.

Comment: I have modified this script http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e19b53170e004e46827b8129d6ef9bfe to create the points that generate the lines... I was thinking I can use the Shape_ID field that the polyline layer has to specify the distance, one of the problems I have tho is alternating which end segment is the first and which is the 2nd.

My end goal is to generate a layer that looks like the black line - http://i.imgur.com/tx5phxg.png

This will allow me to output the file into a FPL format to integrate in a Garmin G1000 (or other aviation GPS)

Comment: It seems that you're really keen to get an arcpy solution to this.. have a read of http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001t000000 which will give the fundamentals, if you use SHAPE@ and return the geometry object you can get the firstPoint and lastPoint (please ensure single part features or that might not be what you really want) which can be used to insert points on an insert cursor. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: The script that is creating the lines, is it making them consistently from a left to right direction? Or does it make them L-R, R-L, L-R, R-L... so its alternating the direction? If it is alternating then what @MichaelMiles-Stimson says is how you would do it.

Comment: @Hornbydd No... It makes them all from a single line. Basically you draw a line at one of the outside boundaries and specify an angle (say 3000 ft @ 90 degrees @ 300 ft spacing). It takes the line and starts at the first point and draws a 3000 ft line @ 90 degrees (north azimuth), then goes down 300 ft and draws another 3000 ft line @ 90 degrees, ect until it runs out of spacing on the line.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - it kinda makes sense.. I am guessing I would generate that for each row but it doesn't help the alternating problem.

Comment: Just work the alternation/increment into the part where you insert the points, the point isn't stored until you call insertRow up until that point you can set a field on it (don't forget to create the field and include it on your insert cursor).

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson http://pastebin.com/wmbi4Siq - I think I have the alternate working (as long as there are only 2 points per row).

Comment: I'm thinking not so much *for part in row[1]:* and *for pnt in part:* but row[1].firstPoint and row[1].lastPoint - parts are for multi-part features if they're single part you can avoid that. There is only one first point and only one last point so any line can be made into two points only.

Comment: Have you got an empty geometry? Use Repair Geometry geoprocessing tool and select *delete features with empty geometry* to clean up the data. It's looking good; when you've finished it post it as an answer to your own question and you're bound to get upvotes - at least one from me.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson http://pastebin.com/NtuLDAWw - This works great (atleast it prints the perimPntLst ... Any help on how to output this as a new point layer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17248/discussion-between-numus-and-michael-miles-stimson).

Comment: Use an insert cursor, a quick how-to http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001v000000 .. It's not that different to reading just the other way around and then call insertRow when done. Of course the feature class should exist first but you can create that on-the-fly using Create Feature Class and then Add Field to store the index in.

Answer (score 1):

```
import arcpy, os 

infc = sys.argv[1] # make sure this is a proper path 
outfc = sys.argv[2] # make sure this is a proper path 

# split the output into a folder and file name 
OutPath = os.path.dirname(outfc) 
OutName = os.path.basename(outfc) 
NameOfFile,ext = os.path.splitext(OutName) # separate file name from extension (if any) 
NameOfFile = NameOfFile + ".shp" # include shape file extension 
OutFC_Clean = OutPath + "\\" + NameOfFile # clean full path to output 

# Get the spatial reference from the input feature class 
desc = arcpy.Describe(infc) 
SR = desc.spatialReference 

n = 1 
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(OutPath,NameOfFile,"POINT",spatial_reference = SR) 
arcpy.AddField_management(OutFC_Clean,"Waypoint","LONG") 

# Enter for loop for each feature 
# 
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@", "alternate"]) as sCur:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OutFC_Clean,["SHAPE@","Waypoint"]) as iCur:
        for row in sCur:
            if row[2] == "False":
                #insert the feature
                iCur.insertRow((row[1].firstPoint,n)) 
                n = n + 1 
                iCur.insertRow((row[1].lastPoint,n)) 
                n = n + 1 
            else: 
                iCur.insertRow((row[1].lastPoint,n)) 
                n = n + 1 
                iCur.insertRow((row[1].firstPoint,n)) 
                n = n + 1
```